# SQL total row count

Tags: sql

I need to select the number of rows:

```
select 
    int_re_usu as Qtd_Respostas 
from 
    tb_questionario_voar_resposta  
group by 
    int_re_usu
```

It  returns:

```
1- 687
2- 375076
3- 339012
4 -314083
5 -52741
6 -339977
7- 276041
8- 373304
9 - 339476
10- 51095
11- 270365
12 - 6
13 - 308670
14 -305232
15 - 85868
16 - 9893
17 -300598
18 - 300572
19 - 275889
20 - 6092
21 - 80092
22 - 307104
23 -273393
```

I want to select instead the number 23,which is the total row_count.

Any ideias?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use @@RowCount

```
select int_re_usu as Qtd_Respostas from tb_questionario_voar_resposta  group by int_re_usu
Select @@RowCount
```

OR
Use a Derived Table

```
Select Count(*) from 
(select int_re_usu as Qtd_Respostas from tb_questionario_voar_resposta  group by int_re_usu) q1
```

Answer (score 6):

Use [COUNT()](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/count.php):

```
select COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT int_re_usu as Qtd_Respostas 
    from tb_questionario_voar_resposta
    group by int_re_usu
)
```

Comment: of course thats not quite...it returns me 23 rows...i want just one single row with the total number of rows

Answer (score 3):

Instead of GROUP BY, you can use DISTINCT:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT int_re_usu)
FROM tb_questionario_voar_resposta
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(*) from
( select int_re_usu as Qtd_Respostas from tb_questionario_voar_resposta  group by int_re_usu ) as a
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the count(*) function.

```
select count(*) 
from table_name 
group by column_name
```

Answer (score 1):

```
With temp as 
( select int_re_usu as Qtd_Respostas 
  from tb_questionario_voar_resposta  
  group by int_re_usu )

Select count(*) from temp
```